# Is there a different way of saying "Steam Engine Time"?

Tags: concept

Steam engine time shows up on urban dictionary, but isn't quite as prevalent beyond that. I'm trying to remember the name of the concept that it's "time" for something to get invented when all the pre-conditions for the invention are in place. It's sometimes used to de-emphasize the inventor by suggesting that if that person didn't pioneer it, someone else would've.

To avoid confusion this is the definition from urban dictionary:

> A period of time when many inventors all over the world, despite isolation from each other, and with no contact with each other in any way, begin inventing a similar technology with a coincidental commonality of ideas.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you thinking of how [the "Heroic" theory of invention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_theory_of_invention_and_scientific_development) is typically contrasted with the [Theory of Multiple Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_discovery)? That is, when [the "time is ripe" for certain ideas](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/114281-when-the-time-is-ripe-for-certain-things-these-things), they are bound to appear?

Comment: "<thing> time," as in *steam engine time* is of course, the correct expression. After all, they might say, early modern things are early modern: **a thing's time** is its own, not any other's. As if to underscore this respectful insistence on **temporal propriety,** &hellip; 
Jonathan Gil Harris, Untimely Matter in the Time of Shakespeare, p.2

Comment: I don't think there's an antonym to the concept of "anachronism." :)

Comment: @DanBron Exactly.

Comment: @Kit This concept is well-studied in the philosophy of science (e.g. Kuhn, Hegel), but I'm not aware of a standard word or term for the "time in which an idea is ripe", unless you want to go all the way out to *zeitgeist*, which seems a bit of a stretch for the invention of the paperclip (to use your example).

Comment: Since the Ancient Greeks had a steam engine, this is a very broad time indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I read your question as referring to a *convergence of conditions*, such as when all the technologies required to construct a new device achieve maturity at the same time that social or economic developments have created favourable market conditions for it.

One example might be the modern microwave oven, where:

> a) the hardware integrates a magnetron with a microcontroller
>   b) postwar marketing methods have created a mass market for gadgets, including in the kitchen
>   c) the frozen meal and the reheatable ready meal have been perfected by food scientists
>   d) the lifestyles of many people mean they have little time for cooking from scratch, and
>   e) many people also haven't been shown (or haven't learned) how to cook for themselves.

Comment: Something very much like that, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Early Industrial Age or Early Industrial Revolution, or to take a still somewhat disputed stand on how to categorize eras, the First Industrial Revolution, or to emphasize the period more emphatically than the process, perhaps the 'era of the First Industrial Revolution'. If this were a certral concept in a paper, I think it would be appropriate to define and use a term like First Industrial Age. Perhaps you could find references in the relevant  literature.

Answer (score 0):

*A new [era](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/era)* is an expression generally used to refer to a specific period of time marked by significant changes: (from dictionary.infoplease.com)

> - a period of time marked by distinctive character, events, etc.: The use of steam for power marked the beginning of an era.
> - the period of time to which anything belongs or is to be assigned: She was born in the era of hansoms and gaslight.

Comment: I think I was a bit unclear, it's not so much about steam engine or about the significance of the event itself. Dawn or era seem to imply it's a grand invention. You wouldn't normally say "The dawn of the paperclip", "The dawn of the toilet seat". I'm looking for something that doesn't give any particular weight to the nature of the invention/idea. Just to describe that it's time for something to come to be.

Comment: @KitSunde - could a'breaktrhough' fit your context?  breakthrough - a productive insight; a significant or sudden advance, development, etc., as in scientific knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

"[Technological inevitability](http://gizmodo.com/5678682/is-facetime-a-technological-inevitability)"?

> The second, more substantial sense of "inevitable" demands a level of common acceptance and viability. A technology's use must come to dominate the technium [defined by the author as "the technological artifice as an aggregate phenomenon," essentially our technological culture as a whole - ed.] or at least its corner of the technosphere. But more than ubiquity, the inevitable must contain a large-scale momentum and proceed on its own determination beyond the free choices of several billion humans. It can't be diverted by mere social whims.

http://gizmodo.com/5678682/is-facetime-a-technological-inevitability

Comment: As links go bad over time, it's always a good idea to quote and attribute in addition to linking; indeed, a link-only answer is one of the pre-populated reasons for deletion votes.